# convert a date from character to numeric

Tags: sas

how can I convert a date (character) variable = 22249 (=30NOV2020) into 30NOV2020 (numeric)?
I tried many ways like input(), put() and so on but without success. Also setting date9., SAS output is: ERROR the format $date9 was not found or could not be loaded.

Many thanks in advance

Best

Comment: The error message you quote is saying that you cannot use a numeric format, like `DATE`, with a character variable.  So SAS tried to help out by assuming you meant the character format `$DATE` instead, but it could not find such a format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a string like '22249' into a number like the date '30NOV2020'd just use the normal numeric informat. Once you have numeric variable with the value 22,249 you can attach any date type format to it to have it be displayed in a way that humans would recognize as a date.

```
data test;
  string='22249';
  date = input(string,32.);
  format date date9.;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    string         date

 1     22249     30NOV2020
```